# How can I filter out which hidden form input types are posted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit, hidden-field

I'm doing a custom checkbox variant, which uses hidden input elements. My problem is that normal checkboxes only post their value to the server, if the checkbox is checked. These custom checkboxes post values no matter what, so I have no way of knowing if the checkbox is actually checked or not, when reading the data server side.

[Here is the fiddle I have used as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/skphh5nq/)

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="checkboxes">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="form-group">       
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <input name="checkbox1" type="hidden" value="0"/>
               <input name="checkbox2" type="hidden" value="0"/>
               <input name="checkbox3" type="hidden" value="0"/>
               <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox1">Yes</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox2">Maybe</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox3">No</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.btn[data-checkbox-name]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="'+$(this).data('checkboxName')+'"]').val(
        $(this).hasClass('active') ? 0 : 1
    );
});
```

Now, in this matter, it actually uses the value of the checkbox to signal if it is checked or not. I however, need an arbitrary number of checkboxes, and I need all of the checkboxes to be able to send a specific value, instead of a name and a 0/1. Yes it is possible for me to programmatically give the checkboxes names where my needed value is a part of the name, and then substring-interpret it server side, but I'd rather return them seperately, for overview and simplicity.

[So here is my version of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/or5x2d43/):

HTML:

```
   <div class="row" id="checkboxes">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="form-group">       
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <input name="checkbox1" type="hidden" value="A" data-value="0"/>
               <input name="checkbox2" type="hidden" value="B" data-value="0"/>
               <input name="checkbox3" type="hidden" value="C" data-value="0"/>
               <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox1">Yes</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox2">Maybe</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox3">No</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.btn[data-checkbox-name]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="'+$(this).data('checkboxName')+'"]').data("value",
        $(this).hasClass('active') ? 0 : 1
    );
});
```

I've pretty much just changed so that it uses `data-value` instead of value, to keep track of it's 0/1 state, which leaves `value` unchanged. But now I have no way of knowing if it is checked or not. Is there a way I can filter the results client side, before sending them, using the `data-value` as a filter value?

I'm already using JQuery, if that helps.

Comment: Is it submitted through AJAX or just as a normal form?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using checkboxes and hiding them in css? That seems to be the general way to solve the problem. You can then attach data using attributes to the checkboxes if needed, but would also just get the checked data automatically. If you're set on using hidden input fields, then presumably you could just add a second data attribute called something like data-checked="true/false"

Comment: @PaulThomasGC Well, the reason is pretty much that I copy pasted someone elses way of doing it. Your way seems interesting though.

Comment: @AlessandroNiciforo, it is a normal form. I would actually like to be able to do it in ajax, and JSON, but I am a little limited in my skills. Normally I only use AJAX whenever my results are to be displayed within the page the user is currently on, or if the purpose is only sending data, while remaining on the same page. I am not quite sure as to how the data flow would be if I use AJAX when the data is to be displayed in a completely different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we don't use AJAX, no need to overcomplicate things. As Paul stated, the general approach is to use standard checkboxes.

```
<div class="row" id="checkboxes">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">       
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="A" class="hide"/>
            <input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="B" class="hide"/>
            <input name="checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="C" class="hide"/>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox1">Yes</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox2">Maybe</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="checkbox3">No</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And

```
$('.btn[data-checkbox-name]').click(function() {
    $('input[name="'+$(this).data('checkboxName')+'"]').prop('checked',
        !$(this).hasClass('active')
    );
});
```

When the form is submitted the default behavior of the checkboxes is preserved: only the checked checkboxes will be sent.

Comment: Yup, I just wrote up a fiddle, as you wrote the answer. This is a way better approach than I was on the track of! Great job, and thanks. Here is my fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/cmxo2y42/